# Covert byte data structure to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I receive a api response as b'[{'key1':'a','key2':'b'},{}....]. I want to convert it to a json and return it from the function. What do I need to convert it into. Please help.

I tried decode("utf-8"), but it returns a string.

```
 result=b'[{'key1':'a','key2':'b'}]'
 f=result.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Is that really the exact response from the API? Show how you're getting it.

Comment: Does the response really have single quotes around strings?

Comment: b'[{"backGroundColor": "aaa","shape":"bbb"},,{}]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```py
import json

json.loads(
    result.decode('utf-8')
)
```

Comment: This won't work if the response has single quotes instead of double quotes as shown in the OP.

Comment: You can specify the tickmarks, separators, and braces as keyword arguments to ```json.loads()```

Comment: exact response format is b'[{"backGroundColor": "aaa","shape":"bbb"},,{}]'

Comment: I guessed ' ' and " " around keys would not matter, but I guess they do. I tried the json.loads() solution by will_f and it works perfect!! Thanks.